# smartctl always returns 226 Workld_Media_Wear_Indic 65535 for Intel 520 Series

Tags: ssd

I have downloaded and built 6.0 smartool, and run it on two different Linux R720 and R710 testing the very same SSD type (Intel 520 Series.) In both cases I got the same Workld_Media_Wear_Indic value - 65535.

I run smartctl -t vendor,0x40 on these devices in hope that it fixes the issue (I know - it actually sets the counter to 65535,) but after running a write test for some time, the value still is the same (65535)

Any idea what is going on? Is there something I am missing?
Note that I have "SMART support is: Enabled" (smartctl -a)

Here is the line orignal line (used xargs echo to remove extra spaces:)

```
~# ./smartctl -A --device=sat+megaraid,3 /dev/sg2 | grep Workld_Media_Wear_Indic | xargs echo
226 Workld_Media_Wear_Indic 0x0032 100 100 000 Old_age Always - 65535
```

Comment: It's going to take you a very long time to get the life down enough to make a dent in a measure that coarse. By my quick "back of the envelope" math, if you do 33TB of writes, you should be able to drop it to 65,534. You could do that in 24 hours or so if you write at full speed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Oh! Then 65535 us really 100% then, and it is X*100/65535 what represents 'freshness' percentage, righr?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: That is actually funny, for on one of the SSDs I have here, after one hour of writing, the number changed from 65535 to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing full speed to SSD (120 MB/s, which is quiet bad, but the machine is not so good,) after 40 minutes I noticed change from 65535 to 1.

smartctl indicates as changed:

```
225 Host_Writes_32MiB
226 Workld_Media_Wear_Indic
228 Workload_Minutes
241 Host_Writes_32MiB
249 NAND_Writes_1GiB
```

smartctl 6.0 has been built on the machine (older version did not support Dell's PERC controller.)
This is how smartctl was called:

```
./smartctl -A --device=sat+megaraid,3 /dev/sg2
```

Thanks to DavidSchwartz for his help.